# Making a form inherit an abstract with 'where'

Tags: c#, .net, forms

So, I need to associate the following abstract...

```
public abstract class BinaryTreeAbstract<T, TL> where TL : BinaryNodeAbstract<T, TL>
{
```

With a form. But I can't make a field out of the abstract, because...

```
    public BinaryTreeAbstract<int, BinaryNodeAbstract<int, BinaryNodeAbstract<.....>>>> Tree;
```

As you can see, the type specification loops.

In all other instances I could make the class itself generic, but...

```
public partial class BinaryTreeDisplay<T> where T : BinaryNodeAbstract<int, T>, Form
{
    public BinaryTreeAbstract<int, T> Tree;
```

The constrains are now conflicting, so, this is also impossible. Or at least, so reads the error. So, at least in the form. This isn't possible either.

So, in summary: How could I define this abstract?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I figured it out.

```
public partial class BinaryTreeDisplay<T> : Form where T : BinaryNodeAbstract<int, T>
```